# Как исправить кодировку?

Tags: java, bitbucket

Добрый день!

Залил проект на bitbucket, но обнаружил что все мои комментарии к коду на кириллице, заменены на ËÎÃÈÊÀ

**Вопрос:** как можно сделать правильное отображение ? 
Работаю в eclipse. Смена кодировки в нём на UTF-8 не помогает.

Comment: Доброе утро. Привести все файлы к utf8, заменить файлы на bitbucket

Comment: а еще лучше комментарии писать на английском ;) это так, оффтопчик

Comment: @bench_doos хорошо, а если программа должна выдавать сообщение на русском языке и не одно тогда каждый раз переписывать ?

Comment: @VargSieg возможно использовать properties для этого?

Comment: @Артём-.....-...-.- поясните, об properties ?

Comment: @VargSieg В properties (http://javadevblog.com/primer-raboty-s-properties-v-java.html) хранится ключ=значение (myButton=Тут мой текст) в кнопку текст подставляется по ключу: .getProperty("myButton") (http://java-online.ru/java-i18n.xhtml)

Comment: @Артём-.....-...-.- вы предлагаете хранить текст для сообщения в свойствах, как вариант, но костыль, суть моего вопроса как закидывать на СКВ не теряя кодировки.

Comment: @VargSieg, окей.. как на счет [вот этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse)?